# Slow Bluetooth connectivity with BTH dongle

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I just built my computer and it doesn't have internal Bluetooth. Hence, I purchased a BTH 3.0 dongle. However, the BTH connectivity it provides is very slow in my computer, and I don't know why. It takes like 2 minutes to pair with a device. I have tested in other computers and it works just fine, so I assume that it is something related to my computer.

I am using Generic Bluetooth Adapter drivers (in my computer and in the laptops), driver version 10.0.18362.693 (in both computers). I have tried the BTH dongle in several USB ports and the behavior is the same. I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the BTH dongle. Any clue on how to solve this?

The computer has the following specs, in case it is relevant:
Motherboard: MSI B450 TOMAHAWK MAX
Processor: AMD RYZEN 5 3600X
RAM: 32GB
Operating System: Windows

I'm connected to internet via ethernet (as my computer also doesn't have wi-fi). I also have two router working at 2.4GHz, and the total number of phones/ computers using that network via Wi-Fi is 5.
This appears to be the problem - so what can I do?

PS. If the 2.4GHz is the problem, why does my laptop (at least the internal BTH) doesn't have the same problem?

Comment: The most likely explanation for the poor performance is signal interference.  Are you using 2.4 GHz WiFi by chance to connect your device to your intranet network?  Bluetooth operates between 2.402 GHz and 2.480 GHz.  **There certainly is a WiFi 2.4 GHz channel that operates on that frequency.** Edit your question to include this vital information required to answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using an ethernet cable to get internet (as the computer also doesn't have wi-fi). Not sure if this helps, or if I need to provide further ifnromation

Comment: Do you have a router that is supports 2.4 GHz?  Do you have wireless phones that run at this frequency?  Please edit your question, to include this information, instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Done, apologies